# Titanium .How to Register device token automatically for push notification using urban airship?

Tags: push, titanium, appcelerator

Hi Titanium developers.
How to register a device token as soon as you open an app? like any regular app that supports push notification.
I checked kitchen sink examples and urban airship but this will need clicking on a button to register the device.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the guides for [Appcelerator Push Notifications through Urban Airship](http://guides.appcelerator.com/en/push_notifications.html). If you want to target Android right now, look for where it links to [UrbanAirship.js](http://guides.appcelerator.com/assets/javascripts/guides/push_notifications/urbanairship.js).

Then when your app loads, you can register their device for push notifications. I hope this helps! Let me know if anything comes up or you have trouble understanding what I've linked.